# Validate date range in a transaction

Tags: validation, genexus, workwithplus

I got this transaction ZENSY0470M to insert data [image: transaction] and this web panel to insert (or update) information into the above transaction
[image: web layout]
[image: rule (to receive parameter when update)]
[image: pattern (using WWP]
[image: ZENSY0470M WW (to show the data)]
[image: Code from the Event Start to get data when updating]
[image: Event when register]
[image: Date validation code]

I'm having trouble validating the date when trying to update a record
For example
If a record has the same key ZENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc = 1, ZENSY0470M_BseCd =1 and ZENSY0470M_EvntCd = 1

- I pick the date range (ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdFrm ~ ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdTo) is 1/10 to 5/10
- The next record which has the same key ZENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc = 1, ZENSY0470M_BseCd =1 and ZENSY0470M_EvntCd = 1 CANNOT have a date in the 1/10 to 5/10 range (1/10, 2/10, ... 5/10), for ex, 30/0 ~ 2/10 would be wrong)
  But when I update a record using the web panel, I need to change the date range from 1/10 ~ 5/10 to 2/10 ~ 6/10, it will trigger the validation, how can I avoid this (I still want to validate the date range, but it needs to exclude the record that I'm updating and compare to other records.
  Thank you!

Comment: I you need any other info, pls ask here, I will post it. Thank you.

Comment: You should add the rules and relevant GX code that makes the validation

Comment: @gusbro I got the rule above

Comment: The rules you should be looking at are the ones from the transaction that yields the validation error. You should add the relevant info of the object that performs the validation.

Comment: @gusbro The validation is in the web panel, this web panel isn't generated from the transaction

Comment: @gusbro I have updated all the necessary info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add in the 'ChkRegister' subroutine the part of the key (ZENSY0470M_TmpltId) that's missing to exclude from the search the record you're updating:

```
For each ZENSY0470M
where ZENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc = &ZENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc
where ZENSY0470M_BseCd = &ZENSY0470M_BseCd
where ZENSY0470M_EvntCd = &ZENSY0470M_EvntCd
where ZENSY0470M_TmpltId <> &ZENSY0470M_TmpltId //Add this line
     If ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdFrm <= &ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdFrm and &ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdTo >= ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdTo
        MSG('1')
        &wErrFlg = Flg.On
     Else
        &wErrFlg = Flg.Off
     EndIf
     If ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdFrm <= ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdTo and &ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdTo >= ZENSY0470M_AplyPrdFrm 
        MSG('2')
        &wErrFlg = Flg.On
     Else
        &wErrFlg = Flg.Off
     EndIf
EndFor
```

Comment: It works, tks you